# how to split the series of no using php

Tags: php

```
     Array([0] =>  1,2,3,4,5)
```

this is the input pattern I have in my code. I have to split this value and need output as below

```
Array ( [0] => 1, [1] =>2, [2] => 3, [3] =>4, [4] =>5 )
```

Comment: He wants to retain the `,` as well. All the solutions here don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$avalues="1,2,3,4,5";
$myarray = explode(',',$avalues);
print_r($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explode

```
$vals = explode("," $avalues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$avalues="1,2,3,4,5"; 
$array = explode(',',$avalues);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: explode Split a string by string

Answer (score 0):

This may be solution,

```
  $avalues="1,2,3,4,5"; 
  $a = explode(',',$avalues);
  var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use explode() function for that which explodes the string based on the character.

```
 $avalues      ='1,2,3,4,5';  
 $exploded_arr = explode(',' , $avalues);


 foreach($exploded_arr as $key=> $value)
 {
    $exploded_arr[$key] = $value.",";
 }

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($exploded_arr);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Doucmentaiton link : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp